Assigning Hex Values from String to an Integer variable
Context: Java 22
I'm trying to read data from a table that includes both Hex and Dec values in a CSV. These values would look something like this:
0x00000000,0
0x03000000,1
0x05000000,2

What I'm having trouble doing is pulling the hex values (0x... included) and assigning them to an int variable.
The declaration int num = 0x05000000; works but when I try to pull these values from the Scanner, I hit a wall.
I need the int variable to include the 0x prefix as I'm using them in to assign color data, which needs the 0x when working with an Alpha channel.
I've gotten to the point where I can pull the Dec value from the table (in either Int or Long form), but don't know how to convert it back to the 0x........ form, while remaining in a numerical data type.
Here's where I've landed so far.
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner("0x000000, 0, 0x03000000, 1, 0x05000000, 2");
        s.useDelimiter(", ");

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            try {
                int num = Integer.decode(s.next());
                System.out.println(num);
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Input Mismatch");
                s.skip(", ");
            }
        }
    }
}

Output
0
0
50331648
1
83886080
2

All of these are Decimal integers. I need them to remain in their "0x..." state as hex integers.
Ideally I'd like an output that reads closer to

0x00000000 (Hex int)
0 (Dec int)
0x03000000 (Hex int)
1 (Dec int)
0x05000000 (Hex int)
2 (Dec int)

I can use any numerical datatype (long, float, double, etc), but I'm having trouble returning the specific hex codes as numerical data.

"I need them to remain in their "0x..." state as hex integers" - so you want strings?

There is a function for this already in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-

Unfortunately this loses the "0x" which I need to keep.

"Unfortunately this loses the "0x" ..." - You are confusing a value with its representation.  Integers do not (cannot) have "0x" prefixes.  An integer is a number, anything with "0x" is a representation.  After reading the data into an integer variable, you must format it correctly on output to match your requirements, and that includes converting to hex and adding back the "0x".


I don't know how to convert it back to the 0x........ form, while remaining in a numerical data type.

This is not possible.  An int is just a number, it isn't hex or decimal.  Only when you display it as a String is it hex or decimal.
If you want to keep it as hex or decimal, you must keep it as a String, not an int.
You can alternately print a number in hexadecimal, with e.g. Integer.toHexString(int), but you will have to know which numbers to display in hexadecimal and which not.

I think I'm getting mixed up with the "not possible". If I can't bring a value back to the "0x..." format, why can I declare it that way?

Because it's convenient sometimes to be able to represent a number as a string of hexadecimal digits, as in your case where you can think of each byte as a part of an RGBA value. But the number in the int variable is physically stored as a binary number. You can represent it as a String in whatever base you like, but the number in the int variable is the same.

Just going back to basics, you know that 16 and 0x10 are the same number? If you write int a = 16; int b = 0x10; int c = Integer.decode("0x10"); then a, b, and c all contain exactly the same number.

Continuing that last comment, int d = 020; //  Also 16. writes an octal numeric literal with the same decimal value of 16.

Thats very helpful. I know my base systems fairly well, but for some reason it wasn't clicking that they all get translated immediately upon declaration. I'm breaking out of Processing and into Java for some visual projects and finding that a lot of the processing libraries are very weird with how they expect data to be input.
Appreciate the help.
